Serialize object fully in one particular location, serialize as a reference ID everywhere else
Intro
I classes that looks like this:
public class ObjectBase
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Object<T> : ObjectBase where T : Object<T>
{

}

public class ObjectA : Object<ObjectA>
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public ObjectB RefToSomeBInstance { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB : Object<ObjectB>
{

}

My data layout to be serialized looks like this:
PersistedObject
  Objects[]
    ObjectA
      RefToSomeBInstance // this is a reference to some ObjectB
    ObjectB // this is the same ObjectB that the ObjectA is referencing as RefToSomeBInstance

The Problem
What I want is for any Object<T> to be fully serialized only if its directly inside of Objects[]. If its located anywhere else it should just its ID. In otherwords I want to end up with this:
PersistedObject
  Objects[]
    ObjectA
      RefToSomeBInstance.ID
    ObjectB

If I were to use Newtonsoft's reference handling out of the box I end up with this:
PersistedObject
  Objects[]
    ObjectA
      RefToSomeBInstance // Fully serialized here with an $id
    ObjectB // $ref to RefToSomeBInstance under the first Object<A>

When what I want is this:
PersistedObject
  Objects[]
    ObjectA
      RefToSomeBInstance // $ref to the ObjectB in Objects[]
    ObjectB // Fully serialized here with an $id

I know that given my current data layout if I just ensure that every ObjectB is first in Objects[] that it will resolve correctly, but my data layout will change in the future and I want more control than that. I don't want serialization order to be a factor here.
What I've Tried
I've been getting around this by manually using a secondary reference class whenever declaring a property that should be an Object<T>:
public class ObjectRef<T> where T : ObjectBase
{
    private T _value;

    [JsonProperty]
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if(_value == null)
            {
                // Go look up value using the ID somewhere...
                _value = SomeService.ResolveObjectById<T>(ID);
            }
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            ID = _value.ID;
        }
    }
}

Then I modify my ObjectA class to look like this:
public class ObjectA : Object<ObjectA>
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public ObjectRef<ObjectB> RefToSomeBInstance { get; set; }
}

Which means anytime I go to use RefToSomeBInstance I have a bunch of .Value invocations everywhere that I'd love to avoid.
I've also tried a bunch of different hacky feeling workarounds using a custom JsonConverter that would try to detect where in the object graph things were being serialized and try to serialize the object in a different way based on context. Didn't really work out and always resulted in reference loop errors.

Do you expect to be able to deserialize this JSON using Json.NET?

@dbc Yes, I'm using Newtonsoft's Json.NET for everything regarding this.
EDIT: To be clear, yes, I want to serialize and deserialize this data.

Json.NET is a single-pass serializer and deserializer.  While you might be able to serialize the "$ref" before the "$id" using appropriate tricks (since they are all in memory), there's no way to deserialize a forward reference to something that hasn't been read yet using a single-pass deserializer.  You would need a second pass to fix them up afterward somehow.

Is your real problem here that you are trying to serialize a linked list and overflowing the stack?  If so, then see maybe JSON.NET StackOverflowException while serialization for one approach.
